# BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() throws exception

Tags: android, bluetooth, libgdx

I try to add Bluetooth to my libgdx android project.
I added the following to the Android manifest:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

I tried to run

```
   mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

in non activity class - exception .
I have read that the class should be activity class.
Okay. I have created

```
   public class BluetoothServer extends Activity {
    ...
       public void GetBluetoothAdapter () {
         mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
      }
    }
```

I ran it as follows:

```
BluetoothServer.GetBluetoothAdapter()
```

Crashes again in the same place.
I tried on two devices with Bluetooth onboard.
Of course, Bluetooth is enabled on these devices. 
I have no idea what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: I say "thanks" for good answers. I could not find "accept" button or such in my previous questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help greatly if you could get the reason for the crash. For some reason you seem not able to access stacktrace, try at least this to see the crash reason:

```
...
try {
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
} catch (Exception e) {

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), 1000);
    toast.show();
}
...
```

Comment: If I do that, I got compilation error "no static method GetApplicationContext() cannot be referenced from static context". I can't make the method GetMyAdapter() non-static. It will not visible from another class as BluetoothServer.GetMyAdapter(). And I am unsure that toast.show() will work because I work in Libgdx render() method.I made it as toast.ToString() which I can show.  Unfortunately I have no experience in writing Activity apps for Android, only some Libgdx experience.

Comment: Wow. I could look at e.getMessage(). It says: "can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: I silly tryed the following:         BluetoothServer.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {...=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
...    Crash again.

Answer (score 0):

To get a BluetoothAdapter representing the local Bluetooth adapter, when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR1 and below, call the static getDefaultAdapter() method; when running on JELLY_BEAN_MR2 and higher, retrieve it through getSystemService(String) with BLUETOOTH_SERVICE.
[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html)