# Android App crashes when Initializing Bluetooth Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I'm developing an Android app but as I am a newbie so can't figure out the solution to the problem. My application crashes when I install it on my Phone (Android 4.3) while it runs fine on the emulator. Though, I know that it crashes when I initialize my Bluetooth Adapter `mBluetoothAdapter`, but dont know the solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
protected static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
Button btnConnect;
int seekVal;
SeekBar seek ;
TextView editText1;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnConnect = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
    editText1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    seekVal = 0;
    seek = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);

    editText1.setText(String.valueOf(0));

    // Crashes when Bluetooth Adapter is initialized 
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // App runs when the above line is commented out
    try{
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device does not support bluetooth device. Sorry but the application will exit now!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
    {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

Here is a part of my MANIFEST

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"></permission>
```

Here is my LogCat

```
01-10 14:55:56.142: E/ResourceType(1027): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010479
01-10 14:55:56.392: I/dalvikvm(1027): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
01-10 14:55:56.392: W/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11341: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
01-10 14:55:56.404: D/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-10 14:55:56.412: I/dalvikvm(1027): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
01-10 14:55:56.412: W/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11347: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
01-10 14:55:56.423: D/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
01-10 14:55:56.423: I/dalvikvm(1027): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged
01-10 14:55:56.423: W/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11349: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged (I)V
01-10 14:55:56.423: D/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
01-10 14:55:56.442: I/dalvikvm(1027): Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
01-10 14:55:56.442: W/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9035: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
01-10 14:55:56.453: D/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
01-10 14:55:56.662: I/dalvikvm(1027): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
01-10 14:55:56.671: W/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11344: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
01-10 14:55:56.671: D/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
01-10 14:55:56.711: I/dalvikvm(1027): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
01-10 14:55:56.711: W/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 366: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
01-10 14:55:56.711: D/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-10 14:55:56.722: I/dalvikvm(1027): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-10 14:55:56.722: W/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 388: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-10 14:55:56.722: D/dalvikvm(1027): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-10 14:55:58.262: D/dalvikvm(1027): GC_CONCURRENT freed 196K, 5% free 7098K/7431K, paused 8ms+5ms
01-10 14:55:58.492: D/gralloc_goldfish(1027): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: isn't there a stacktrace in logcat, that you can post here?

Comment: @helleye, Plz see the updated question for the same. But kindly note that the app runs find on emulator but crashes on the phone.

Comment: Is this the complete logcat output, when your app is running (and crashing) on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem was of insufficient user permission in the `Manifest`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11469502/1584140 helped me to use try catch for getting the actual error.

Finally I solved my issue by setting up the permissions like this.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```